# What if the wifi server has "Security Recommendation" next to it and it will not connect to internet?

Tags: iphone

Is there a work around or setting change that will help if the wifi server has "Security Recommendation" next to it and my iphone 6 will not connect to internet?

Answer (score 1):

The '*security recommendation*' will display whenever your iPhone sees an unsecured wireless network (meaning you don't need a password to join).  It has nothing to do with your ability to connect to the internet.  That message is just to let you know that anything sent over that wifi connection will be visible/unencrypted.

If the owner of that wifi connection, let's say a school, for example, doesn't allow that connection to access the internet, then you won't be able to access the internet.  It's as simple as that and there's no workaround or shortcut to allow you access.

If the connection *does* allow internet access and you still can't get on the internet, there could be a problem with your iPhone or with that connection.